# Help understanding epsilon definition of supremum

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, epsilon-delta

I have a question regarding trying to prove that a number is supremum of the set:
$ A=\left \{ \frac{4n}{n+1}:n\in \mathbb{N} \right \} $.
Clearly 4 is an upper bound to the set. But how can i prove for example that the number $ 10$ is not the supremum of $A $?

**My attempt:**
If $s = sup(A) $ there exist no number $10 - \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $a > 10 - \varepsilon$ where $a \in A$.
I am trying to prove this by contradiction where I am assuming that this number exists and arrive at the following:

$\frac{4n}{n+1}>10-\varepsilon\\\\\Leftrightarrow 4n>(10-\varepsilon)(n+1)\\\\\Leftrightarrow -6n+\varepsilon n > 10 - \varepsilon\\\\\Leftrightarrow n(\varepsilon-6)>10-\varepsilon\\\\\text{case:} \ \varepsilon\geq 6:n>\frac{10-\varepsilon}{\varepsilon-6}\\\\\text{case:}\ \varepsilon <6:n<\frac{10-\varepsilon}{\varepsilon-6}$

I dont understand how to interpret this result really and would appreciate any explanation.

Comment: We see that for $\varepsilon < 6$ there is no such $n \in \mathbb{N}$ because natural numbers are positive  and $\frac{10-\varepsilon}{\varepsilon - 6}$ is negative.

Comment: You're making things much too complicated. As you say, $4$ is an upper bound. The supremum is the *least* upper bound, so it must be less than or equal to $4$. We have $\frac{4n}{n+1} \le 4 < 10 - \epsilon$ whenever $\epsilon < 6$ as psl2Z says.